In an application created on Vert.x using AsyncFile and HttpClientRequest, the file is not loaded to the end
The following libraries are used in this part of the code written in vert.x:

vert.x 3.5.4;
io.vertx.core.http.HttpClientRequest;
io.vertx.core.http.HttpClient;
io.vertx.core.file.OpenOptions;
io.vertx.core.file.AsyncFile;
io.vertx.core.streams.Pump;
io.vertx.core.streams.ReadStream;
io.vertx.core.streams.WriteStream.

Java 8 is also involved in the code.
The launch takes place in Docker
These tools are key in the process of downloading the entire file.
I will demonstrate only those parts that are directly involved in the code, without describing the entire process.
Consider the following class:
public class LoadVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

private HttpClient client;
// any fildes ...

@Override   
public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
       super.start(startFuture);       
       this.client = ClientUtils.createHttpClient(vertx, config());

     vertx.eventBus().consumer(EVENT_DOWNLOAD,           this::handleDownload);

}

private void handleDownload(Message<Object> event) {
    final JsonObject eventCtx = (JsonObject) event.body();
    final DownloadContext ctx = DownloadContext.fromJson(eventCtx);

    final long alreadyDownloaded = FileUtils.getFileSize(ctx.getTmpFile());
    final String rangeHeader = alreadyDownloaded > 0 ? "bytes=" + alreadyDownloaded + "-" : null;

    logger.debug("Start. Context: {}", eventCtx);
    HttpClientRequest request = client.getAbs(ctx.getUrl(), response -> {
        logger.debug("Response received: Status {}", response.statusCode());
        
        if (response.statusCode() == 200 || response.statusCode() == 206) {
            response.pause();
            final long totalSize = response.headers().contains(HDR_CONTENT_LENGTH)
                    ? Long.parseLong(response.headers().get(HDR_CONTENT_LENGTH))
                    : -1;
            ctx.resetTotal(totalSize);
// todo code ...
            OpenOptions fileOpts = new OpenOptions().setCreate(true).setWrite(true).setAppend(true);
            //todo code ...

            vertx.fileSystem().open(ctx.getTmpFile(), fileOpts, future -> {
                if (future.succeeded()) {
                    AsyncFile file = future.result();
                    
                    final PumpProgress downloadPump = new PumpProgress(response, file, bytesPrgs -> {
                        dJob.progress(bytesPrgs);
                        // todo code ....
                    }, ChecksumBuilder.create());
                    
                    downloadPump.setWriteQueueMaxSize(1024 * 1024);
                    
                    response.endHandler(dummy -> {
                        downloadPump.stop();
                        //todo code ...
                    });

                    response.exceptionHandler(e -> {
                        downloadPump.stop();
                        // todo code ...
                    });

                    downloadPump.start();
                    response.resume();
                } else {
                    handleDownloadError("Unable", future.cause(), ctx);
                }
            });
        } else if (response.statusCode() == 304) {
            handleDownload304("No new updates", ctx);
        } else {
            handleDownloadError(String.format("Bad response: %s %s", response.statusCode(), response.statusMessage()), null, ctx);
        }
    })
    .exceptionHandler(e -> handleDownloadError("Unable to request get", e, ctx));

    //todo code...
    request.end();
}


private class PumpProgress implements Pump {
    private final ReadStream<Buffer> readStream;
    private final WriteStream<Buffer> writeStream;
    private final Handler<Buffer> dataHandler;
    private final Handler<Void> drainHandler;
    private final ChecksumBuilder csb;
    private int pumped;
    private long pumpedBytes;
    private Consumer<Long> deltaProgress;

    public PumpProgress(ReadStream<Buffer> rs, WriteStream<Buffer> ws, Consumer<Long> deltaProgress, ChecksumBuilder csb) {
        this.readStream = rs;
        this.writeStream = ws;
        this.deltaProgress = deltaProgress;
        this.pumped = 0;
        this.pumpedBytes = 0;
        this.csb = csb;
        drainHandler = v -> readStream.resume();
        dataHandler = data -> {
            writeStream.write(data);
            incPumped(data.length());
            if (csb != null) {
                csb.accept(data.getBytes());
            }
            if (this.deltaProgress != null) {
                this.deltaProgress.accept((long) data.length());
            }
            if (writeStream.writeQueueFull()) {
                readStream.pause();
                writeStream.drainHandler(drainHandler); 
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Pump setWriteQueueMaxSize(int maxSize) {
        writeStream.setWriteQueueMaxSize(maxSize);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Pump start() {
        logger.debug("Pump started");
        readStream.handler(dataHandler);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Pump stop() {
        try {
            writeStream.drainHandler(null);
            readStream.handler(null);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            logger.error("closed. Error: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int numberPumped() {
        return pumped;
    }

    private synchronized void incPumped(long buffSize) {
        pumped++;
        pumpedBytes += buffSize;
    }

    public synchronized long getPumpedBytes() {
        return pumpedBytes;
    }

    public synchronized ChecksumBuilder getChecksum() {
        return csb;
    }
}

}

In this case, a request is made to a third-party service to download a large zip file, the weight of which is 60 gigabytes. Other downloads of various files may occur in parallel, including smaller files. Everything happens asynchronously.
However, when the download of the zip file begins, it stops at 5, 10 or 15 gigabytes, without completing the process. Previously, when the file weighed 30 gigabytes, there was no such problem. The RAM of the machine is 16 gigabytes. Linux OS
Sometimes, if you call the download again, it may not even start. But the strangest thing is that there are no errors or exceptions in the logs! The last percentage of the download is simply displayed, after which the process stops. At the same time, the program works and continues to download small files, but problems arise with a large zip file.
I do not know where or how to look for the problem, as the download just stops. In the method, you can see how I read and write bytes to the file system so as not to overload the memory.
Can you tell me how to solve this problem? I don't want to increase the resources of the machine, since there are so many of them. Perhaps the problem lies in the implementation.
I have limited the heap size in Java by changing the parameters from -Xms8192 -Xms12288 to -Xms6144 -Xms10240. This made it possible to avoid memory overflow, since its volume was limited. After that, the file download process probably started to go better, and eventually it was uploaded, but the weight of the zip file was 35 gigabytes. And the file may be larger.
I also tried changing the garbage collection parameters from Parallel GC to -XX:+UseG1GC, but it didn't give any result.
In addition, in the PumpProgress method, I called the flush() method, although this was not a mandatory step. However, this not only did not help, but also brought down the percentage of progress. But that's another story...
